# Притяжательное к «дядя Вася» — «дяди Васин»?

Tags: орфография

Есть просторечное «дядя Вася», а на вопрос «чей?» отвечают: «дяди Васин». Как это правильно писать?

1. дяди Васин
2. дяди-Васин
3. дяде-Васин
4. дядивасин
5. дядевасин

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Серж, такое написание действительно регламентируется в ПАС, у Розенталя его нет. А что есть у Розенталя?

1. [**Розенталь. § 39. Сложные прилагательные**](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49)

> 7. Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, образованные от сочетания имени и фамилии, имени и отчества или двух фамилий, например: *вальтер-скоттовские романы, жюль-верновская фантастика, робин-гудовские приключения, джек-лондоновские произведения, лев-толстовский стиль, ерофей-павловичская платформа* (от названия станции *Ерофей Павлович*), *бойль-мариоттовский закон, ильфо-петровская сатира, Иван-Иванычев пиджак, **Анна-Михайловнина** кофта.*
>
> **Примечания**: 1. В отдельных случаях встречается слитное написание таких прилагательных: *козьмакрючковская удаль, тарасобульбовская сила* и др.
> 2. Прилагательное, образованное от иноязычной фамилии, перед которой стоит служебное слово, пишется слитно: *дебройлевская гипотеза* (ср. де Бройль).
> 3. Прилагательные, образованные от восточных составных собственных имен лиц (китайских, корейских, вьетнамских и др.), пишутся слитно: *чанкайшистская клика* (ср. *Чан Кайши*), *хошиминовское правительство* (ср. *Хо Ши Мин*).

2. [**ПАС под ред. Лопатина**](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1899)

> § 166. Имена прилагательные, образованные от личных имен, фамилий, кличек при помощи суффиксов *-ов (-ев)* или *-ин* и обозначающие индивидуальную принадлежность, пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.: *Рафаэлева Мадонна, Шекспировы трагедии, Гегелева «Логика», Далев словарь, Иваново детство, Танина книга, Муркины котята*. Однако в составе фразеологических оборотов и в составных терминах прилагательные с *-ов (-ев), -ин* пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: *ариаднина нить, ахиллесова пята, каинова печать, прокрустово ложе, сизифов труд, гордиев узел, демьянова уха, тришкин кафтан, филькина грамота; ариэлева невесомость, архимедов рычаг, вольтова дуга, бикфордов шнур, базедова болезнь, виттова пляска, рентгеновы лучи, венерин башмачок* (растение).
>
> С прописной буквы пишется вторая часть сложных прилагательных типа ***дяди-Васин**, дяди-Стёпин, тёти-Валин, бабы-Дусин* и обе части прилагательных типа *Иван-Иванычев, **Анны-Петровнин***.
>
> Прописная буква пишется и в наречиях с приставкой *по-*, образованных от прилагательных на *-ин* типа *Танин, Петин*, напр.: *по-Таниному, по-Наташиному, по-Петиному, по-тёти-Валиному, по-Анны-Петровниному*.

3. Получается, что ***дяди-Васин*** – это нововведение? У Розенталя самый близкий вариант – это ***Иван-Иванычев** пиджак, **Анна-Михайловнина** кофта.*

Но здесь первое слово **не склоняется**, а у нас-то склоняется: ***дяди-Васин***, *тети-Валин*.  Вот что мне не понравилось.

Тогда надо писать так: ***дядя-Васин***, *тетя-Валин*. Тоже некрасиво, уж лучше ***дяди Васин.***

4. А вы как думаете? Вопрос ко всем участникам форума.

Comment: Не имею ничего против такого написания. Где-то читал объяснения Лопатина. Найду — вышлю.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.  А вот мне дефисное написание совсем не нравится. Конечно, это не книжная речь, а передача разговорного стиля на письме, и встречается такой вариант редко.  Вот и кажется он чужим в языке, не успеваешь  к нему привыкнуть. А вот «дяди Васин» в глаза никак не бросается, так как отдельные слова часто встречаются.  Да и логика при использовании дефиса нарушена – такое письмо характерно для тех случаев, когда первая часть не склоняется.

Answer (score 1):

Грамота.ру считает правильным вариант №2:

> С прописной буквы пишется вторая часть сложных прилагательных типа
> дяди-Васин, дяди-Стёпин, тёти-Валин, бабы-Дусин и обе части
> прилагательных типа Иван-Иванычев, Анны-Петровнин.

[Вопрос №282736](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=282736)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но мне хотелось бы уточнить (может быть, вы знаете). Такая орфография указана в ПАС под ред. Лопатина,  и  Грамота. ру, вероятно, ссылается на него. А у Розенталя есть указание по написанию таких слов? Это нововведение или нет? Насколько оно распространено в художественной литературе? Честно говоря, мне не нравится такое письмо.
Почему нельзя написать так:  дяди Васина книга. Книга (кого? чья? ) дяди, книга (чья?) Васи, Васина книга. Такая форма выглядит более привычно для глаз, так как оба написания встречаются в притяжательном значении.

Comment: @Sharon, насколько я помню, в справочнике Розенталя такие не написания не регламентируются. Это ПАС.

Comment: Серж, я ответила на два ваших комментария. Посмотрите. пожалуйста.

Comment: @Sharon, какие два комментария? Я вроде один комментарий писал.